# Visual studio can't find definition for TakeDamage from another method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making health and damage script  in Unity.
I have error CS0117 'PlayerHealth' does not contain a definition for 'TakeDamage'

I want player to have 20 healths and when touched an object it will damage him.
I tried searching on google but I didn't find answer.

PlayerHealth script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 20;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

And for EnemyDamage script I use this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int DMG;
    float cooldown = 0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(cooldown);
        cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        PlayerHealth health = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        if (cooldown <= 0)
        {
            if (health != null)
            {
                PlayerHealth.TakeDamage(DMG);//here is the error
            }
            cooldown = 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call `TakeDamage` as if it were a static method in the `PlayerHealth` class. It's actually a method in the `NewBehaviourScript` class, which doesn't appear to have anything to do with `PlayerHealth` (and isn't referenced anywhere within `PlayerHealth`). How were you expecting the compiler to find that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PlayerHealth.TakeDamage(DMG);` tries to call a static method `TakeDamage` on the class `PlayerHealth` but there is no such method, hence the error.
Your code is a little mess anyway, lets clean it up.
Attach this script to your game objects which can lose health (e.g. a player):

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour // you called it NewBehaviourScript
{
    public int health = 20;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        health -= damage;
        if (health <= 0) {
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

Attach this script to your game objects which can inflict damage:

```
public class Damage : MonoBehaviour  // you called it PlayerHealth (?!)
{
    public int DMG;
    float cooldown = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(cooldown);
        cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (cooldown <= 0f) {
            Health health = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>();
            if (health != null) {
                // call TakeDamage on the collided >instance<
                health.TakeDamage(DMG); 
            }
            cooldown = 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you a starting point with an appropriate colliders setup.

Comment: small note, when you rename the class you also have to rename the script

Comment: Ah thx @Voidsay , that can cause some confusion to the unwary.